# Get gnome-3-like windows with custom headerbar

Tags: c++, gtk3, gnome, gtkmm

## My Problem

I'm working with Anjuta/gtkmm/C++ and want to design a program that looks similar to other gnome 3 programs.

This includes that big draggable Headerbar with custom buttons on it and other visual effects like the bigger background shadow behind the window.

### Black Bar Issue

So far I discovered the `GtkHeaderBar` Widget. I also discovered that you can use `main_win->set_titlebar(*header_bar);` to make it draggable. Furthermore I ticked the "Client side window decorations" check box in the glade plugin (inside Anjuta).

However now it looks like in the image below. How do I get rid of that black bar?

### Compatibility with other Desktops

Another question is how to maintain compatibility with other DEs? My bet would be to have two different glade/xml files (or one part of it in two external files). One contains the code that generates the gnome-3-like window and one that generates a normal one. When loading the program it is decided which file should be loaded based on the fact whether it is running under gnome 3 or any other desktop environment. But what is the best way to determine if the DE is gnome 3?

[image: screenshot with black bar on top]

### Update

When I untick "Client side window decorations" and "Decorated" the black bar is gone. But the shadows and the rounded corners are also gone.

[image]

Is the way I'm doing this even the right one? How should it be done?

Comment: [mcve] would help and keep to one question only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

## Black bar issue

To get this cool gnome bar in glade without having one of the aforementioned issues follow these steps:

1. Tick "Client side window decorations" in the "General tab" in the window properties. Make sure that "Decorated" is ticked, too, even if it is greyed out. You can tick (or untick) it while "Client side window decorations" is unticked.

[image]

2. A new space at the top of the window should appear

[image]

3. Place a header bar inside it

[image]

4. (Optionally) Tick "Show window controls" in the "General" tab of its properties and give it a title and a subtitle

[image]

**Voila:**

[image]

Note that something like `main_win->set_titlebar(*header_bar);` isn't even needed. There's nothing specific that you have to do in your code to make this work.

## Compatibility

It seems the only way to maintain compatibility is the way already described in the question post. The best way to determine if gnome-shell is running or if the right version of GTK+ is used is the one below. (Or at least the best one I came up with). It uses the function `exec` from here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/3139807).

```
//is gnome-shell running?
std::string gnomeString = exec(
    "pgrep -lx \"gnome-shell\" | head -1 | cut -d \" \" -f2"
);
//get version string
std::string gnomeVersionString = exec(
    "gnome-shell --version | sed -e \"s/GNOME Shell //\""
);

//parse version string to int array; not 100% necessary, but nice to have
std::vector<int> gnomeVersion;
std::stringstream ss(gnomeVersionString); std::string item;

while (std::getline(ss, item, '.'))
    gnomeVersion.push_back(std::atoi(item.c_str()));

//optional requirement for gnome-like header bar:
bool isGnome3 = gnomeString == "gnome-shell\n" &&
                gnomeVersion.size() > 0 &&
                gnomeVersion[0] >= 3;

//absolute requirement for gnome-like header bar:
bool correctGTKversion = gtk_major_version >= 3 &&
                         gtk_minor_version >= 10;

std::cout << "isGnome3: " << (isGnome3?"yes":"no") << "\n";
std::cout << "correctGTK+: " << (correctGTKversion?"yes":"no") << "\n";
std::cout << "gnome version: ";
for(int v : gnomeVersion)
    std::cout << v << ".";
std::cout << "\n";
```

Comment: You do not need to spawn another process to obtain the environment variables. These can be obtained by using    std::string = Glib::getenv("GDMSESSION"); . In addition GDMSESSION can be set to "default" and still be running the gnome-shell, or any other shell.

Comment: @Errolvandel'Isle thx for the tips. I used http://askubuntu.com/a/227669/232476 as a source for my original code. But I came up with a more robust method now.